# Compare products has moved to right side in sidebar, Magento2

Tags: magento2

How to bring the Compare products option to the left side from my custom module.

[image]

Where is it being called?

In my custom module, it is appearing to the right side.

Comment: Please refer `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\default.xml`

Comment: But how come for my other custom modules its coming to the right, for  one of my custom module, i get it to the left.

Comment: Check your Layout file , Use `layout="2columns-left"` or  `layout="2columns-right"`

Comment: cool... i had used 3 columns in layout, i updated to layout="2columns-left"..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer **vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\default.x‌​ml**

In your Layout file , Use `layout="2columns-left"`